# Summing up two floats always returns 0.0 in MIPS

Tags: mips

I'm writing my very first program in assembly, I just have to sum up 2.5 and 2.5
Here's my code

```
.data
    #2.5+2.5=5.0
    myNumber1: .float 2.5
    myNumber2: .float 2.5
.text
    lwc1 $f1, myNumber1
    lwc1 $f2, myNumber2
    
    add.s $f3, $f1, $f2
    
    li $v0, 3
    syscall
```

For some reason it always returns 0.0 in the output, but in the memory it seems to sum and store the value in $f3 correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) the syscall to print a float is 2 not 3. Also, you must have the float to print in register $f12.

Accordingly, this should work:

```
add.s $f12, $f1, $f2

li $v0, 2
syscall
```